# How can I dynamically build a path for redirect_to in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a number of models that can be edited in more than one area of my application. I am trying to avoid the need for lots of if/else statements in the update/create/destroy controller methods to determine the correct "on success" redirect paths. I am also hoping I can abstract this enough that I can put it in the `application_controller` and make use of it any where needed.

As a simplified example I have this ER model:

```
class FinancialStatement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :financial_year
  has_many :budgets
  has_many :revenue_projections, through: :budgets
end

class Budget < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :financial_statement
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :revenue_projections, dependent: :destroy
end

class RevenueProjection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :potential_debtor, class_name: "Client", optional: true
  belongs_to :budget
  has_one :tenant, through: :budget
  has_one :division, through: :budget
end
```

Users can perform some/all the CRUD operations on RevenueProjection objects from under a FinancialStatement or under a Budget depending on use cases and access levels etc. (I may even want the same for under a budget under a financial statement)

These are the relevant portions of the routes:

```
  resources :financial_statements do
    resources :revenue_projections do
    end
  end

  resources :budgets do
    resources :revenue_projections do
    end
  end
```

So I have a half solution that mostly works and will show more clearly what I would like to happen. Here is the `update` method in `revenue_projections_controller.rb`:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @revenue_projection.update(revenue_projection_params)
        format.html { redirect_to cud_redirect_path(@ancestors, @revenue_projection), notice: action_success_message }
        format.json { render json: { status: :ok, location: @revenue_projection }}
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: { errors: @revenue_projection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }}
      end
    end
  end
```

`@ancestors` is an array of parent objects set elsewhere from URL params that in this case is only one generation deep but I do have use cases for up to 3 levels of nesting (in deliberate but hopefully not misguided violation of the conventional wisdom about nesting routes). I am happy with the `cud_redirect_path` method signature and its definition looks like this.

```
  def cud_redirect_path(ancestors, object = nil)
    path_extension = ancestors.blank? ? '' : (ancestors.map { |anc| anc.class.name.underscore }.join('_') + '_')
    if object
      send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name}_path", ancestors, object)
    else
      send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name.pluralize}_path", ancestors)
    end
  end
```

The `if object` branch does not do what I want, basically ignoring the last argument to send.  I tried passing `(ancestors + [object])` which was close but put "." instead of "/" in the URL. The only way I have made it work is by laying out the array element by element manually, which means branching based on the length of the ancestors array and violating DRY principles. I tried to find a ** equivalent operator that would work on an array parameter but couldn't. If this were Common Lisp I would use `#'apply`.  I will be surprised if Rails, with all its path-finding magic, can not provide a nice way to accept a variable length list of parents plus an object and return the correct path, it has yet to disappoint me!  I have a nagging feeling I have already seen that somewhere too...

Thanks in advance!

[update]
ChatGPT offered me this:

```
def cud_redirect_path(ancestors, object = nil)
  path_extension = ancestors.blank? ? '' : (ancestors.map { |anc| anc.class.name.underscore }.join('_') + '_')
  if object
    send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name}_path", *ancestors, object)
  else
    send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name.pluralize}_path", *ancestors)
  end
end
```

Which got my hopes up, but sadly does not work any differently.

Comment: `have use cases for up to 3 levels of nesting (in deliberate but hopefully not misguided violation of the conventional wisdom about nesting routes)`  you know the way out of this hole already. simplify your roots, what you did seems extremely overcomplicated and absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: can you explain "simplify your roots"? For context, one of the goals of the application is to provide users the means to interrogate dollar figures starting at broad summary values and drilling down, sometimes all the way to a source cost, eg. a line on an order. It is important to retain the context of the users path.  Happy to consider other approaches.

Comment: Sorry meant routes not roots! So users really change urls by hand? Can't this be solved with navigation within the app?

Comment: D'oh! Sorry, I should have figured routes, was not trying to be intentionaly obtuse....No, the links within the views resolve the path with all the ancestor ids embedded. My issue is really about making it easier for the programmer so controllers will chose the redirect path without a lot of ```if pamams[this_id]...if params[that_id]``` etc

Comment: There is another super class controller that handles finding all the parent objects in one place, the controller subclasses can just rely on @ancestors having the objects they will need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel here. The [polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) will already handle this for you.

Given this crazy example:

```rb
resources :blogs do
  resources :categories do
    resources :posts # Much nesting, such wow!
  end 
end
```

```rb
@ancestors = [Blog.find(1), Category.find(2)]
@record = Post.find(3)
```

As long as your route follows the Rails conventions you can simply pass an array containing all the records:

```rb
redirect_to [*@ancestors, @record]
# shorthand for 
redirect_to(
  polymophic_path([Blog.find(1), Category.find(2), Post.find(3)]
)
```

This will call:

```rb
blog_category_post_path(blog_id: 1, category_id: 2, id: 3)
```

And result in the path `/blogs/1/categories/2/posts/3`.

It does all the work by using the [`ActiveModel::Naming API`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-singular_route_key) which contains methods to derive the path helper names from the class name.

If you want to redirect to the index instead of a specific record you can do:

```
redirect_to [*@ancestors, @record.class]
```

Which will result in the path `/blogs/1/categories/2/posts`.

Comment: Thanks, max, it does exactly what I need. I thought there would have been something ready made in Rails tool kit.

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question, the method definition that does the trick is:

```
  def cud_redirect_path(ancestors, object = nil)
    path_extension = ancestors.blank? ? '' : (ancestors.map { |anc| anc.class.name.underscore }.join('_') + '_')
    if object
      send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name.singularize}_path", *ancestors, object)
    else
      send("#{path_extension}#{controller_name}_path", *ancestors)
    end
  end
```

Note the need to singularize `controller_name` in the `if object` branch, it is already pluralized for the `else`.